# UITableView refuses to populate on my Device

Tags: iphone

I am using a Data.plist file to populate my UITableView/Navigation-based Application with data.  it works perfectly on the simulator, and it shows up all 261 names, with the subtitle.  The detail view also works 100%.

But, no matter what I do, reboot, clean, comment out, it refuses to show up on my Device.  (iPhone 3G, unfortunately.  Soon to be iPhone 4).

I have a Footer on my Table View that calculates the amount of Cells and totals them up for me.  "Movies: 261" is what it shows.  Yes, my app is an in-house only app that is my DVD Index.

But, on the Device, it shows "Movies: 0" even though the Data.plist is there, and everything should be working.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?  Can anyone help me?

Thank-you.

Comment: Which version of iOS is running on your device? If it is an older one (3.x), maybe your app is using methods that have been introduced in iOS 3.2 and are thus unavailable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, problem fixed.  Turns out the iPhone itself is ***CaSe SeNsItIvE*** where as the Simulator is not.  So, if the PLIST file you're using is called "Data.plist" and it's referenced as "data.plist" in your code, it will NOT populate on the Device.

I hope this helps everyone who had the same problem as I did.  :)

Thanks,

BenBen